# join table for each variable

Tags: mysql, json

lets say i have 2 tables:

table 1:

```
PersonID      PersonName
1             Micheal
2             Edward
3.            Nord
4.            Stephanie
```

Table 2

```
PurchaseID      PurchaseItem.      PersonID
1               Rack               1
2               Desk               1
3.              Lamp               2
4.              Table              3
```

with standard join, query result can return

```
1      Micheal     Rack
2.     Micheal     Desk
3      Edward      Lamp
4      Nord        Table
```

but i need the result to be shown as:

```
1      Micheal     Rack, Desk
2      Edward      Lamp
3      Nord        Table
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could group by the `PersonName` and use `group_concat` to concatenate the `PurchaseItem`s:

```sql
SELECT   t1.PersonId, PersonName, GROUP_CONCAT(PurchaseItem, ', ')
FROM     t1
JOIN     t2 ON t1.PersonId = t2.PersonId
GROUP BY t1.PersonId, PersonName
```

Comment: hi in actual its not just Purchase Item that need to show.

Comment: @FaizalNor so please edit your question with the actual result you want to get

Comment: lets say your if the row is return only 1, the comma still there

Comment: @FaizalNor `group_concat` won't add the separator (`', '` in this case) if there's only only value.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
Select t1.personid, t1.personname, group_concat(t2.purchase_item) 
from table1 t1 join table2 t2
on t1.personId = t2.personId
 group by personID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.personid, t1.personname,
       group_concat(t2.PurchaseItem)
from t1
join t2 on t1.personid = t2.personid
group by t1.personid, t1.personname
```